# CakePHP application cannot start in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, xampp

I'm trying to get a CakePHP application to work. I use xampp and put my application files in /xampp/htdocs. For .htaccess configuration I refer to  http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/37/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess . After that I'm trying to run my application, but I've got this message in browser.

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
```

All my other applications  in which I have not used the CakePHP, runs well on localhost, without  any errors. I think the problem connected with .htaccess. Any suggestions ?

**EDITED**
My .htaccess files

```
**/xampp/htdocs/app/webroot/.htaccess**

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

**/xampp/htdocs/app/.htaccess**

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

**/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess**

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What does your apache's error log say?

Comment: Other meesages are about  ports 80, 443... 
[Sat Apr 21 17:24:47 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/xampp/htdocs/follow/app/webroot/.htaccess: <IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existance of specified modules

Comment: In [this article](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/82647/P45) related to CodeIgniter, it seems to suggest that the character encoding of the `.htaccess` could be the problem. Have a look and see if that helps you.

Comment: Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think your .htaccess files look correct. You might need to tell Apache where the webroot of your app is. 
Try adding a vhost entry in your Apache configuration

inside `\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

try adding something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot c:\xampp\htdocs\app\webroot  <-(use the actual path here)
</VirtualHost>
```

The you should then be able to access the CackPHP app by visiting `http://localhost`
Be sure to remove any other VirtualHost blocks that might conflict, although if you are working with a fresh copy of XAMPP everything in this file will be commented out.
Don't forget to restart Apache for the change to take effect.